# Is this a proper subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $\{ [x \,\, y] : xy \geq 0 \}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$? I was told that it was not, as addition does not hold.

Any comments?

Comment: Check for addition.

Comment: Vector space over $\mathbb R$? Just the set or the space generated by it?

Comment: In your title you ask whether it is a *proper* subspace. In the question itself you leave that out. What is your real question? Secondly: is $[x,y]$ just the notation for ordered pair, or for something else?

Comment: @drhab meant to be a 2d vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at $[1,0] + [0,-1]$.

Comment: Is $[x,y]$ the notation for ordered pair here? If so then by definition $\{[x,y]|xy\ge0\}\subset\mathbb R^2$ and I don't see the need of looking at $[1,0]+[0,-1]$ for this (so I don't understand the upvotes).

Comment: @drhab I assumed, because $x$, $y$ are probably real numbers and some people don’t like round parantheses. The question is tagged linear algebra, so I assumed that *subspace* is meant to be *linear subspace*. I will of course remove my answer if these assumptions are false. While I don’t think it’s such a great answer that it deserves as many upvotes as it got, I personally don’t understand the downvote.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. To make things clear: I am not the downvoter.